# How should Old School RuneScape questions be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Last year, RuneScape released a version of the game that reverted to the 2007 state of the game, wiping all accounts. This is in response to the "Evolution of Combat" update that completely changed how combat works. This clearly has an impact on how questions should be asked, since while much of the content is similar, the OSRS version lacks many updates.

I created a [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) tag to differentiate the two. But I'm wondering how they should be tagged going forward.

#### Option 1: Just the [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) tag should be applied

Pros: updates to old content would not cloud the relevant answers.
Cons: content that wasn't updated would be applicable to both, but users that only follow the vanilla [runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runescape) tag won't see it.

#### Option 2: Nixx the [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape) tag

The exact opposite of option 1, it increases total exposure to questions, but introduces contamination.

#### Option 3: Both should be applied to all questions

This option makes it clear that it applies to RS07, so users know to not apply updates to their answers, but still increases exposure. This is my recommendation.

#### Option 4: Both should be applied depending on the content of the question.

This would get tricky, as either way you risk both contamination or exclusion.

I can't think of anything like this applying to other games. How should we proceed with these kinds of questions?

Comment: I asked [something similar](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/revisiting-the-dwarf-fortress-tags) about Dwarf Fortress.  We never did get a consensus on that one.

Comment: If only there was a magical consensus button we could press for problems like these... =(

Comment: Sadly, the best we can do is muddle through.  Such is life, after all.  Hopefully we do manage to come to a consensus for Runescape, though.

Comment: Just an aside - Is 'Oldschool Runescape' the *official* name or the fan-name? We should use the official name wherever possible (and if the fan name is overly popular, potentially synonymise it with the official name as well)

Comment: It's the official name - oldschool.runescape.com

Comment: cool thanks :-)

Comment: My eyes are twitching - I'm sure the tag should be [old-school-runescape]

Comment: @corsiKa if you go to that URL, every instance of "Old School" is two separate words, including in the name of the game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly suggest option 1. We should treat Old School Runescape as a different game, that happens to be somewhat similar to modern Runescape.

Runescape gets updated *every week*. When you remove 8 years of that, you get a game that is substantially different in many important ways.

But Old School Runescape is not *just* the modern game minus 8 years of weekly updates. It has its own updates, so it is now essentially a fork of the game, and it has some content modern Runescape *never* had.

Comment: I like it. And I don't like it. There's obviously pros and cons to each option. But it's a direction we can standardize on, and if we find a better way we can go that better way later.

Comment: Do you think we should also have a "runescape3" tag, and make "runescape" a disallowed tag, since it's ambiguous>

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. Runescape 3 is still the primary game: it's the one they advertise, and the one you see if you go to runescape.com. I think it might be worth having "runescape3" as a synonym though.

Comment: The other problem with removing the "runescape" tag is that the string "Runescape 3" does not currently appear on the front page of the website or in the game. Relatively new players may be confused that neither runescape tag corresponds to the title of the game they play.

Comment: Don't use "runescape3" as a primary tag. It is only a matter of time until Jagex decides that they reached a milestone and tag it "runescape 4" or something along those lines. That wouldn't invalidate all "runescape 3" questions, since it is essentially the same game.

Comment: is there a tag for classic runescape?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but such a tag should probably be [runescape-classic], since that's what the game is called.